# My bot cant play or talk inside the vc, Cannot play audio as no valid encryption package is installed

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, distube

i am making a music bot for on discordjs v14 but i dont know why this error showing up even tho i have installed discordjs/opus and voice + i have installed ffmpeg and ffmpeg-static
this is the the error:

```
/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:490
  throw new Error(`Cannot play audio as no valid encryption package is installed.
  ^

Error: Cannot play audio as no valid encryption package is installed.
- Install sodium, libsodium-wrappers, or tweetnacl.
- Use the generateDependencyReport() function for more information.

    at Object.fallbackError (/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:490:9)
    at Networking.encryptOpusPacket (/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:795:17)
    at Networking.createAudioPacket (/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:785:49)
    at Networking.prepareAudioPacket (/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:731:33)
    at VoiceConnection2.prepareAudioPacket (/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:1527:29)
    at /home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:1106:50
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AudioPlayer._preparePacket (/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:1106:15)
    at AudioPlayer._stepPrepare (/home/runner/v14-2/node_modules/@discordjs/voice/dist/index.js:1090:14)
```

Im using distube to play music on this.

Answer (score 2):

Install libsodium-wrappers by using `npm i libsodium-wrappers`

[Here is the guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/#installation)